# Stacked Bar chart of many columns grouped by the values of one column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I have a Pandas dataframe like this

```
'BondInvestments' |'Cash' |'EquityInvestments'| 'MoneyMarketInvestments' | 'Cluster'
10                | 1     | 10                |  20                      | 0
10                | 3     | 10                |  20                      | 1
200               | 1     | 15                |  20                      | 1
10                | 1     | 10                |  10                      | 2
10                | 1     | 10                |  20                      | 0
13                | 3     | 10                |  20                      | 2
200               | 1     | 15                |  20                      | 1
10                | 1     | 10                |  10                      | 0
```

I would like to create a horizontal stacked bar chart grouped by 'Cluster'. How can I do it in Python? I'd prefer using matplotlib but any other suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if only the style you don't satisfy, just try another style use [`plt.style`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plt.rc('figure', figsize = (10,4))
df.groupby('Cluster').sum().plot.barh(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.plot.barh`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html):

```
df.set_index('Cluster').plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

Comment: it works, but it's really slow and all the bars are united making the graph impossible to understand. I've been looking at their documentation and I couldn't find a way to make it look better https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html